# need help on trying to make it where my users can change their own font size and color with php

Tags: php, html, css, session

so here is my code. i've tried all day to figure out what i have done wrong and finally i figured id ask for help. i got the background working and my users can change it but to be able to change the font size and color i cant figure out why it wont work? it could be some thing small but i cant figure it out so can some one help me?

```
<?php

session_start();


// If the form was submitted, them set the session variable
if (isset($_POST['theFTsize'])) {
$_SESSION['ftsize'] = $_POST['theFTsize'];
}
if (isset($_POST['theFTcolor'])) {
$_SESSION['ftcolor'] = $_POST['theFTcolor'];
}
if (isset($_POST['theBGcolor'])) {
$_SESSION['bgcolor'] = $_POST['theBGcolor'];
}


// Set session to variables
$ftsize = isset($_SESSION['ftsize']) ? $_SESSION['ftsize'] : '30px';
$ftcolor = isset($_SESSION['ftcolor']) ? $_SESSION['ftcolor'] : 'green';
$bgcolor = isset($_SESSION['bgcolor']) ? $_SESSION['bgcolor'] : '#660066';
 ?>

<style>
body {
background-color:<?php echo $bgcolor; ?>;
font-color:<?php echo $ftcolor; ?>;
font-size:<?php echo $ftsize; ?>;">
}
</style>

<p>please choose font size. </p>
<form method="post" action="members_only.php">
<input type="text" name="theFTsize"/>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<p>please choose a font color. </p>
<form method="post" action="members_only.php">
<input type="text" name="theFTcolor"/>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<p>please choose a background color. </p>
<form method="post" action="members_only.php">
<input type="text" name="theBGcolor"/>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: `font-color` should be `color`

Comment: the background will change. but the font size or color wont change.

Comment: i tried it as font-color. didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
font-color:<?php echo $ftcolor; ?>;
```

it should be

```
color:<?php echo $ftcolor; ?>;
```